# Different out for same function in Java against Python

Tags: java, python

I have a formula to evaluate

```
((x+y-1)*(x+y-2))/2 + x
```

and get the string representation of it.
So in Java 1.7 I write

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = 99999;
    int y = 99999;
    int answer = ((x+y-1)*(x+y-2))/2 + x;
    String s = Integer.toString(answer);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

and in Python 2.7

```
def answer(x, y):
  z = ((x+y-1)*(x+y-2))/2 + x
  return str(z);

print(answer(99999,99999))
```

Java gave me the out put of `672047173` while Python gave me `19999400005` and seems the value from Python is correct. What is the reason behind this difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`19999400005` is a too large value for `int` variables, so the Java calculations would overflow.

Use `long` variables instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    long x = 99999;
    long y = 99999;
    long answer = ((x+y-1)*(x+y-2))/2 + x;
    String s = Long.toString(answer);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output is:

```
19999400005
```

Also note that you can print `answer` directly and don't have to convert it to `String` explicitly:

```
System.out.println(answer);
```

Comment: Java calculations definitely overflow in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Because integer range in java is minimum -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

> int answer = ((x+y-1)*(x+y-2))/2 + x;

In this line you are assigning higher range value to integer. It causes integer overflow on the arithmetic operation. So that is why you are getting incorrect value to get correct value you have to use **Long** data type.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int x = 99999;
    int y = 99999;
    long answer = (((x+y-1)*1l)*((x+y-2)*1l))/2 + x;
    String s = Long.toString(answer);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: This will still not work. `int * int` gives result in `int` and then assign it to `long` so still you would get answer with affection of `integer overflow`. If you want to do same with `integer` you can do as `1L * (x+y-1) * (x+y-2)` this will now do `multiplication` operation in `long`.

Comment: You are wrong here. Implicit casting will be done after multiplication operation and multiplication will be done in integer data type which will cause an overflow and give you wrong answer. You can check by running your snippet.